# I need to be able to display an embedded image to a new page when a button is clicked, I dont know what im doing and here is what ive tried

Tags: javascript, html

Here is what ive tried I cant seem to get it to work. The function only navigates me when I have plain text in the document.write.

```
function Function(){
    document.write("<iframe>Imbed here</iframe>")
  }
```

Comment: Why not just use an <img> tag?

Comment: You broke it further after editing

Comment: Are you calling the function?

Comment: I just used a built in embed code from imgur, how would the <img> work?

Comment: Could you show the embed code?

Answer (score 0):

You have nested quotes...

Try:

```
function QuizFunction(){
    document.write("<iframe class='imgur-album' width='100%' height='550' frameborder='0' src='http://imgur.com/a/202Qn/embed'></iframe>");
}
```

Comment: ;] faster than me! and inverted answers! :D

Comment: I treid your suggestion and the button for the function  still refuses to change the page.

Comment: so whats the console saying @MaxFischer

Comment: Try adding a semicolon at the end of the document.write.

Comment: The semicoling didnt do anything